# jQuery: Parent or Sibling? And how to 'instruct' a sibling search?

Tags: jquery, selector, parent, siblings

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<li class = "current_parent level-0">
  <a> Parent Link </a>
  <ul class= "children">
     <li class = "level-1">
           <a> Link to child </a>
     </li>

     <li class = "level-1 current_page_item">
          <a> Link to child </a>
     </li>

     <li class = "level-1">
           <a> Link to child </a>
     </li>

     </ul>
</li>
```

Basically, I want to get the HREF of the  element one level UP and one level DOWN from the current_page_item .

I can get the URL of the current_page_item > a easily enough via .attr(), i.e. $('.current_page_item').attr("href");.

But how can I tell jQuery to look one level up? .parent() doesn't seem right, because they're not parents, they're siblings,right?

But how can I tell siblings to move UP or DOWN a list?

Basically I want $('.current_page_item > ONE LI > A UP').attr("href"); and $('.current_page_item > ONE LI > A DOWN').attr("href");.

Again, thanks for the help on my jQuery n00bquest!

Answer (score 3):

If you'r starting with the `<li>` use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`.prev()`](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) to get the next/previous siblings, for example:

```
var prevHref = $(".current_page_item").prev().find("a").attr("href");
var nextHref = $(".current_page_item").next().find("a").attr("href");
```

You can find a complete functions to move around like this as well as their descriptions under the [Tree Traversal section of the jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Answer (score 0):

use .prev() instead of .parent() (.prev() and .next() both refers to siblings)